# how to serve build folder with pm2

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pm2, npm-build

I am trying to serve my node.js and react application with pm2 including loading data from mongoDB.
So far I can serve the build with `serve -s build -l 3001` i am using port 3001 for the front end.
And `pm2 start server.js` for the backend which runs on port 3000. **This runs and loads data successfully.**

However, instead of using pm2 start server.js I want to be able to run `pm2 serve build/ 3000` with my app name however when I do this my web page turns blank, all responses are 200 and there is nothing in the logs.
I have also checked online and searched many resources all result back to exactly what i am currently doing.

I am using `npm run build` to create my build folder.

Does anyone know a way to successfully serve your react build directory with pm2 ?

Thank you!